# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 128, 128) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 128, 128, 1)'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a placeholder with the shape `(?, 128, 128, 1)`

```
net_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 128, 128, 1])
```

Then, I used a numpy array with the shape `(32, 128, 128, 1)` to feed the above placeholder:

```
input_image_batch = input_image_batch.reshape(32, 128, 128, 1)

pre_output_image = sess.run(network, feed_dict={net_input: input_image_batch})
```

It gave me this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 128, 128) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 128, 128, 1)'
```

I printed the shape of input_image_batch, that is no problem.

```
print(input_image_batch.shape)
(32, 128, 128, 1)
```

TensorFlow might automatically squeeze the last axis while feeding and don't know why `TensorFlow 1.13` version has this processing?

Comment: Then, try an earlier version like `tensorflow 1.14` and see if the error persists

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and edit! There is a typo. I am using TF 1.13 version.

Comment: I tried 1.14 and it is also not work.

Comment: I've installed `tensorflow 1.13` and tried your code without the variable `network` and the shape was exactly as expected. Could you post `network` to your question?

Comment: Thank you, @Anwarvic! But the network code is too long to post here. Where can I post it? I slightly modified the code (input one channel instead of three RGB channels) from this repo, and I am using the Encoder-Decoder-Skip net. https://github.com/GeorgeSeif/Semantic-Segmentation-Suite

Comment: It's OK, but I didn't help you yet :)

Comment: I can change the placeholder with the shape of (?, 128, 128) instead of (?, 128, 128, 1) and add if inputs.shape.ndims == 3: inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, axis=-1) in the network part. Then, the code can run. However, I don't understand why it changed the numpy shape while feeding? It is weird.